# OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs missing business information

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client

I'm looking at the list of [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) trying to find the right scope that allows access to business information, but can't seem to find it.

I'm looking specifically to access my client's reviews left by their customers using API. Which scope should I use?

*** EDIT ***
This is the desired scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage
```

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

Comment: Hi, thanks but no. This is the old API and to the best of my understanding it's being deprecated. The API is moving to work with discovery API as stated in the link above, but I can't find the discovery doc for the business API.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest

Comment: @RotemPerets, seems like they're posted here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples under each name of the API (new ones are there too)